# Transpose convert column values of multi dimensional array into flat array

Tags: php, arrays

initial array is looks like this:

```
$arInitial = Array(
  0 => Array(1,2,3), 
  1 => Array(3,4),
  2 => Array(5,6,7,8),
  3 => Array(9)
);
```

The resulting array should be:

```
Array(1,3,5,9,2,4,6,3,7,8);
```

I was thinking about while(1) loop, but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: So this is not just sorting. You also want to merge several arrays into a single one.

Comment: @Jocelyn I agree, it's not only sorting. I need some thoughts how can i implement this

Comment: a loop is the only option i see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are myriad of ways to get this, there's already a collection of array incantation function that does this, I just can't find the dup question yet, but another way is just to `array_shift` each batch:

```
$result = array();
$max = count($arInitial);
for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    foreach($arInitial as &$a) {
        if(!empty($a)) {
            $e = array_shift($a);
            $result[] = $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try two functions:

- [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
- [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) *With sort_flags*

Probably you want something like

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($arInitial as $array){
    $finalArray = array_merge($finalArray, $array);
}

var $finalArray = array_unique($finalArray , SORT_NUMERIC);
```

That way you should get the result you want.